# Options for heating a stainless conical fermenter

Tags: fermenter, diy

I have two 15g stainless conicals in a fridge and I am building an advanced controller to heat and cool the whole mess. Some details on my [blog](http://www.finack.com/beerhacker/frak) for those who are curious.

Currently I use a [Fermwrap](http://morebeer.com/view_product/16674//The_FermWrap_Heater) from More Beer to heat the conicals but I feel it works much better for carboys. The fermwrap is hard to get on the conical in such a way to maximize contact and heat transfer. I also want more juice then 40w so I would have to have 4 of these just to cover to conicals.

I have the thermwells, controllers, and cooling figured out, just not an optimal solution for heating.

The question: Can you recommend a good way to heat 15g SS Conical Fermenters?

Comment: Looks interesting, I'd recommend putting the link to http://www.finack.com/beerhacker/frak.  Just curious, why do you heat inside a refrigerator?

Comment: I heat in the fridge because I may be running two different brews and fermentation schedules or in the winter, too cold :)
Will change the link.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using those [heating mats/ribbons](http://www.warmzone.com/under-floor-heat.asp) used for tile floors and just wrap it around your fermenter.